# Add new record only when all forms are filled out

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013, microsoft-reporting

I'm creating a new database in ms access. I've created all forms already.

How can I set up my forms and buttons so that a new record is added to their respective tables ONLY when the required fields in all forms are filled out?

I have 8 forms for the user to fill out for each"customer".  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are clicking a button to submit the form, you can have an `On Click` event for that button which will run the following code:

```
Private Sub button_Click()

if ([field1].Value = "" or isnull([field1].value)) Then
    MsgBox "Fill out all the required fields before submitting"
    End
else 
    'Submit record using DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO....."
End If

End Sub
```

Have a chain of if statements to check all the fields that you want to be filled out.

If you really want to have a chain of forms that open one another and then submit all forms together at the end, try this:

Using an `On Click` event for a button in the first form, open the next form, followed by running the macro/code to submit the record. In the next form do the same. Basically this keeps adding to a stack, and when the last form is called and submits the record, it finishes the `On Click` event and the code returns to the form before. The form before will move to the next line of code which is to submit the record and then that code finishes and the same thing happens. Here is a little pseudo code:

On form 1:

```
Private Sub button_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm 'enter parameters to open next form here
'Code to submit record
'DoCmd.CloseForm 'form name

End Sub
```

On form 2, form 3, and so on:

```
Private Sub button_Click()

DoCmd.OpenForm 'enter parameters to open nextform here
'Code to submit record
'DoCmd.CloseForm 'form name

End Sub
```

Make sure you use the parameter acDialog when using DoCmd.openForm to pause the code. You will have to close the form after in order to jump back to the previous code. I added some more to the code above. Follow this link for more information about pausing the code http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/pause-code-while-waiting-for-a-popup-form-to-close.1155074/

Comment: So you want to be able to fill out all 8 forms before submitting them? Can I ask why? If there are errors with the data or something happens where you can't submit a record for a table, then it would defeat the purpose of submitting all of them at once. I would say definitely don't do that. Stick to one form at a time, what you are trying to do is very complicated and unnecessary for the data entry process.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of your form? I'm confused as to what you mean by that last comment. Also in the future I would get away from using bound forms especially if you want to do something like this. VBA is much better for the complex stuff